# Cloudflare point to my site, but Css is not working

Tags: css, wordpress, web-hosting, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare and pointing DNS to my website (000webhostapp using Wordpress). but CSS format is not working in my site. Whereas I use default DNS from web hosting or my DNS(not through Cloudflare), it works properly. please help me! thanks

Comment: If you changed the `http` to `https` you need to change to all related style or script.

Comment: Sorry. could you say more? I did not really get it

Answer (score 1):

Most likely mixed content error. 
Mixed content is when your site is loading over HTTPS, however your code have references to images, scripts or css resources over HTTP so the browser blocks it from being loaded.
Please review the console logs in your browser's developer tools to verify this.

Cloudflare have an excellent guide on [Troubleshooting mixed content errors](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170476-Troubleshooting-mixed-content-errors)
.

Enabling "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" feature in your Crypto tab of your Cloudflare dashboard usually prove to be an easy fix.